# Split Action Bar in ListActivity not shown / ActionBar Icons in ListActivity not shown

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

in my android application i have a few Activities which extends ListActivity. What i want is to have a split ActionBar and or Icons in my ActionBar in those extended Activities. 
Currently it doesent work. The Items in ListActivities are just shown in the onCreateOptionsMenu (three dots). I just created a simple layout for a test and modifided my manifest file.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/new_game"
      android:title="t1"
      android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"/>
<item android:id="@+id/help"
      android:title="t2"
      android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
    <item android:id="@+id/help2"
      android:title="t2"
      android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
        <item android:id="@+id/help3"
            android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
      android:title="t2"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
```

and in my manifest i tried to add the following to the application tag or just to the ListActivites.

```
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
               android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
```

In Activities which extend ActionBarActivity everything is running correct. Am i missing something for ListActivities? Does anyone have an idea?

help would be awesome! thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to remove `app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"` or change it to `app:showAsAction="always`

take a look at [this lik](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html)

**ifRoom** : Only place this item in the Action Bar if there is room for it.

**withText** : Also include the title text (defined by android:title) with the action item. You can include this value along with one of the others as a flag set, by separating them with a pipe |.

**never** : Never place this item in the Action Bar.

**always** : Always place this item in the Action Bar. Avoid using this unless it's critical that the item always appear in the action bar. Setting multiple items to always appear as action items can result in them overlapping with other UI in the action bar.

Comment: thanks for your answer. it works now somehow. i cant really tell why ;) i changed it to always and back but both work now. i added now the meta data tag to every activity in my manifest.
Sadly the splitbar is not working for listactivities. do you have an idea why?

Comment: try to extend your class to ListActivity and override method onCreateOptionsMenu to bind your action bar to the activity:        public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_action_bar_name, menu);

        return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
    }

}

Answer (score 0):

Okay i guess i figured out why it doesent show the splitactionbar. In addition to the meta tag you need to set the attribute uiOptions for a ListActivity + use the android namespace.

```
android:showAsAction="always"    
android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

This option is only used for API Level 14 and higher. For Versions lesss than that ive no Idea so far to solve the problem.